# Angular 2 Webpack environment configuration at runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, build, webpack, environment-variables

I'm using Webpack to build my Angular project.

I have an `env.js` file that looks like:

```
module.exports.ENV = {
  API_URL: "http://localhost:5001/",
  ...
};
```

And in my `webpack.common.js`, I have:

```
const API_URL = require('./env').ENV.API_URL;
const METADATA = {
  API_URL: API_URL,
  title: "Angular Project",
  ...
};
```

This is nice because I am able to configure my environment variables in a single `env.js` file. However, this configuration is in the build process. This is bad because I cannot just build once and run in every environment (given the environment has a `env.js`), instead, for each environment, I have to build a new instance of the project - which I don't think is the best practice.

So my question is: is there any way I can configure my environment variables at runtime with Angular 2 and Webpack?

Answer (score -1):

Webpack recommends using process.env.NODE_ENV:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/

I've used this in many places:

```
const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
```

There is another library package `cross-env` that you can call on command-line to set the environment variable, and execute a process at the same time.

You could also define your environment variables from your webpack plugins (via the DefinePlugin):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
}),
```